# Jenkins JIRA Issue Updater plugin Returns 400 Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

Tring to update a custom field In JIRA using Jira Issue Updater Plugin, returns a 400 error. Attaching screenshot of the configuration.I'm missing something here??

[image]

**RROR:Unable to connect to REST service
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://host:8443/rest/api/2/search?jqlFinished:**